# How to fetch data from Dynamodb to flutter project?

Tags: flutter, amazon-dynamodb, flutter-web

Currently, I'm working on a project that uses DynamoDB as the database. I want to display or fetch the data that I stored in the DynamoDB to my Flutter project's dashboard. The dashboard that I want to build will contain the information that I have gained and stored in the DynamoDB such as temperature readings from a sensor.

Comment: Hi Jono! This question is unfortunately quite broad, and mostly the answers here would be to recommend libraries or opinions about different approaches, which is not something SO is well suited for. Maybe if you have a question more in the form of "I tried this, but this happened, and i expected this other thing to happen" you'll have more luck :)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.